# Setting up static DNS and Alternate DNS server programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, dns, ip-address, static-ip-address

I found this code as i search on google. I just want to change my DNS server to static. I just dont know where to put my static DNS and Alternate Dns Servers here. Please help me. Thanks :)

```
Public Sub setDNS(ByVal NIC As String, ByVal DNS As String)
   Dim objMC As New ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
   Dim objMOC As ManagementObjectCollection = objMC.GetInstances()

   For Each objMO As ManagementObject In objMOC
      If CBool(objMO("IPEnabled")) Then
         ' if you are using the System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface you'll need to change this line to if (objMO["Caption"].ToString().Contains(NIC)) and pass in the Description property instead of the name 
         If objMO("Caption").Equals(NIC) Then
            Try
               Dim newDNS As ManagementBaseObject = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder")
               newDNS("DNSServerSearchOrder") = DNS.Split(","c)
               Dim setDNS As ManagementBaseObject = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", newDNS, Nothing)
            Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
               Throw
            End Try
         End If
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Any HELP would be so much appreciated. Thanks in advance.